# How do I make my device discover-able to nearby device without confirmation dialog via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I had make an application related to Bluetooth connection in Android, every time when I enable Bluetooth, it shows a confirmation dialog that make your device discover able no near by device.

Is there any way to make device discover able without confirmation dialog.

**I had used this:**

```
Intent Intent= new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);       
Intent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
```

Comment: Based on my understanding there is not any way around this. Probably an Android security reason, or maybe just related to how Android allows the user to interact with making the device discoverable. The negative thing about making the device discoverable without a dialog or the user being explicitly shown it is that it drains battery/resources and allows your device to be more vulnerable since people can see your device (that is the security reason from my understanding).

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful:

```
try {
  Method bluetoothDeviceVisibility;
  bluetoothDeviceVisibility = bluetoothAdapter.getClass().getMethod("setScanMode", int.class, int.class);
  bluetoothDeviceVisibility.invoke(bluetoothAdapter, BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE, 0);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```